# How to Create a generic Iterator Extension Method with Predicate Function and Selector to Create a Special Grouping Method

Tags: vb.net, lambda, iterator, extension-methods, ienumerable

I am dealing with an old outdated 4D database that our Sales Department is still clinging to. I have created an ODBC connection to read from the tables, and have been creating visual dashboards for our Executives and Managers.

To help understand.. A typical database might have an Order Table, and a OrderDetails table.

This database has a Proposal Table, and a [Line Items] Table. Further, instead of a possible 3rd child table (say, OrderRelease) that relates back to a given orderDetail, this database just has the Singular aforementioned [Line Item] Table, and there is not any relation relating one lineitem child to a parent lineitem. (A LineItem can have additional Line Items that go with it)

Example:

```
    | ProdCode |  Price  | FeatureNum | LineNum | SortOrder | NoFeature |
    |   ProdA  | 100,000 |            |    1    |     0     |   FALSE   |
    |   ProdA  |    0    | ProdA_SF1  |    2    |     1     |   FALSE   |        
    |   ProdA  |    0    | ProdA_SF2  |    3    |     1     |   FALSE   |   
    |   ProdA  |  5000   | ProdA_OF1  |    4    |     2     |   FALSE   |
```

Now.. there could be more than one ProductA in an order, each with their own configuration of special Features, etc.

Looking at the original Code inside 4D, the application would step Line by line, and trigger a Subtotal Render when:

- Line Items' [NoFeature] is True
- A new Line Item record is loaded and that record has a different Product Code
- The last Line Item is being evaluated
- The Line Items' [Feature Number] is blank and the Line Item being evaluated is not the first Line Item.

What I am trying to do is set up an Iterator Extension Method that will handle this custom grouping, and return an Ienumerable of the Main Line Items with their Price set to the rendered Subtotal.

Here is what I have so Far:

```
  <Extension>
Public Iterator Function SpecialGrouping(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T),
               ByVal predicate As Func(Of T, Integer, Boolean), ByVal Selector As Func(Of IEnumerable(Of T), T)) As IEnumerable(Of T)

    Dim start As Integer = 0

    While start < source.Count()
        Dim enumerable = source.Skip(start).TakeWhile(predicate)
        start += enumerable.Count
        Yield Selector(enumerable)
    End While

End Function
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong with my Generic Extension method implementation. I want to call it like this:

```
Dim lineItems = GetLineItemsMethod ''for simplicity's sake
Dim subTotalRenderedMainItems = lineItems.SpecialGrouping(
    Function(x, index) Not (x.NoFeatures OrElse (x.LineNum <> 1 AndAlso x.FeatureNum = Nothing) OrElse index = 0),
    Function(x)
        Dim MainItem = x.OrderBy(Function(y) y.LineNum).FirstOrDefault
        MainItem.Price = x.Sum(Function(y) y.Price)
        Return MainItem
    End Function)
```

Any and all help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is very convoluted, as it restarts re-enumerating the source during its evaluation. I would choose an approach where you can iterate with a simple `For Each`.

```
<Extension>
Public Iterator Function SpecialGrouping(Of T)(
    source As IEnumerable(Of T),
    isNewMainItem As Func(Of T, T, Boolean),
    initializeMainItem As Action(Of T),   'E.g. set price to 0.0
    aggregate As Action(Of T, T)   'E.g. add price of subitem (2nd param) to main item (1st param)
) As IEnumerable(Of T)

    Dim currentMainItem As T = Nothing

    For Each x As T In source
        If isNewMainItem(currentMainItem, x) Then
            If currentMainItem IsNot Nothing Then
                Yield currentMainItem
            End If
            currentMainItem = x
            initializeMainItem(currentMainItem)
        ElseIf currentMainItem IsNot Nothing Then
            aggregate(currentMainItem, x)
        End If
    Next
    If currentMainItem IsNot Nothing Then
        Yield currentMainItem
    End If
End Function
```

The method takes these parameters:

- `source` an enumeration of `T`
- `isNewMainItem` a function delegate returning `True` when a new group begins. The first parameter is the current main item, the second is the item being enumerated. This allows you to compare the product codes of the two.
- `initializeMainItem`. To sum up the prices, you must initialize the sum, i.e. the `Price` of the main item, with 0.
- `aggregate` combines the main item with a sub-item.

Example

```
Dim lineItems = GetLineItemsMethod()
Dim subTotalRenderedMainItems = lineItems.SpecialGrouping(
    isNewMainItem:=Function(main, x) main Is Nothing OrElse main.ProdCode <> x.ProdCode _
        OrElse x.LineNum = 1,
    initializeMainItem:=Sub(x) x.Price = 0.0,
    aggregate:=Sub(main, x) main.Price = main.Price + x.Price
)
```

During the first iteration `main` is `Nothing`. Therefore we can test this instead of testing index=0. You may have to fine tune the condition in `isNewMainItem`.

If some items do not have to be summed up, then the corresponding logic would go into the `aggregate` delegate. E.g.:

```
aggregate:=Sub(main, x) main.Price = main.Price + If(x.NoFeatures, 0, x.Price)
```

Comment: This seems like it could work, but one caveat.. the initializeMainItem.. it sets the price to Zero.  The MainItem lineitem itself is the BASE price, with all the optional features being added to it.

Comment: okay, then we can simply drop the `initializeMainItem` parameter, if you simply want to add prices of sub-items the existing main item. Or pass an empty one as parameter `initializeMainItem:=Sub(x)
                            End Sub` where `End Sub` is on the next line.

Comment: Ill edit my original Post to add this, but I felt like I better explain it. the  NoFeatures property is a Boolean that the original programmer uses to Break off a subItem into its own Maintem. Luckily if this is the case,there will not be any subsequent line items that still belong to the previous mainitem..

Comment: It would help if you extend your example to contain several groups.

Comment: isNewMainItem:=Function(main, x) main Is Nothing OrElse main.ProdCode <> x.ProdCode OrElse x.LineNum = 1 OrElse x.NoFeatures OrElse x.FeatureNum = Nothing

I believe this will take care of it...
let me test it

Comment: This Works!  I was pulling my hair at first, until I remembered I needed to ensure they were in Order BY Line Number... then Viola!

Comment: Well.. Scratch that.. The grouping works, but for some reason the price shown is only the MainItem Price.. it isnt adding the subitems to the total.

Comment: Ok.. Changed   aggregate:=Function(main, x)  TO  aggregate:=Sub(main, x)

Comment: Yes it should. Corrected it. I'm not sure, why the compiler didn't complain.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much for your help!